# Indentation in RubyMine 2017.1

Tags: rubymine

Just updated RubyMine to 2017.1 and get new strange auto-indentation behavior:

- the first line in method indents with 2 tabs
- next lines indents with 1 tab

[image]

My settings was set to Defaults:

[image]

Ho to get the same indentation for the first definition and following?

Answer (score 0):

guess, you should submit a bugreport to the youtrack with screencast and your codestyle file. I could not reproduce this behavior, everything works as expected.

Comment: thx, I've fixed this after removing of `$PROJECT_FOLDER/.editorconfig` file, which I had created at some moment before. Probably there was some mess.